# Is it possible to remotely install an app on an iOS device from the web/iTunes?

Tags: ios, itunes, applications, ios-appstore

A valuable feature of the Google Play Store is the ability to command a device you've signed in on to download an app without needing to go searching for the app on the device. I would like to do the same on iOS, but the [iTunes Preview](https://itunes.apple.com/us/) interface doesn't look like it supports signing in and cuing up app downloads on a device. Is it possible to tell an internet-connected iOS device to download an app from your computer either online or through the iTunes store browser?

Comment: Partial duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/178154/182550

Comment: I have removed the [mdm] tag because the goal of this is not to utilize non-Apple resources, even if it's accessible through an Apple-provided API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - iOS supports this out of the box with many MDM frameworks to push updates to iOS devices over the air. There are some free / open source MDM, but I would recommend something hosted like bushel that has better support and has been running a while.

- http://bushel.com

If you need to host the MDM yourself, Apple's server app includes Profile Manager and would be my recommendation for your first server. (It's well documented, inexpensive, handles sertificates well and enables push notification registration.)

- https://www.apple.com/osx/server/

Comment: I'm not looking for a framework or updates. I'm a user trying to easily add an app to my device without syncing through iTunes or opening the App Store on my iOS device.

Comment: What you want is not possible without using an MDM. We manage hundreds of iPads at my school, and we can install and delete apps from all of the, remotely, using our MDM.

Comment: @user2943160 the three options in my answer are the best chance you have. There is no other back door unless you jailbreak.